# Affine Springer fibers for symmetric spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, springer-fibres

Springer fibers are defined to be the varieties of "isotropic" full flags which are fixed by a certain element in the symmetric space. In a similar manner, affine Springer fibers can be defined.

In [this 2015 paper by Polák](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04703), the dimensions of affine Springer fibers are determined when involution-invariant subgroup is two-blocked and the fiber is over a regular semisimple element. My question is:

> Can the dimensions of affine Springer fibers for symmetric spaces over semisimple elements be determined in general? What else has been done on affine Springer fibers for symmetric spaces?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just to add information that might not be useful; 5-10 years ago some friends and I computed some affine Springer fibers for the symmetric space given by the involution $g\mapsto (g^t)^{-1}$ for $GL_n$ (namely the symmetric pair $(GL_n, O_n)$). Unlike usual affine Springer fibers, the new one is no longer equidimensional. Even worse, the regular locus no longer has the maximal dimension, so the same idea of the dimension formula by computing that for the regular locus as by Bezrukavnikov would not work.